# Disable Policy Warning Feature on Pending Changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a couple of .tfignore files that have poorly formed ignore patterns within them. And these .tfignore files just keep getting put into our shared TFS workspace. We've tried removing them before, but they keep getting checked back in.

The problem is that with these bad patterns the Pending Changes tab in Visual Studio's Team Explorer view finds over 5000 warnings. These takes over a minute to add to the display, and Visual Studio becomes unresponsive while it is populating.

Is there a way to disable the Policy Warning's feature of Pending Changes?

A picture of the Pending Changes window: http://tinypic.com/r/168d72c/8

PS. My current work around is to wait for the initial load of the window, then minimize the Policy Warnings feature. Which helps prevent reloading the list as long as I always directly select the files I want to check-in from the Solution Explorer. But, I would really like a way to disable the feature.

Comment: Please attach your picture through the Stack Overflow widget (which uses imgur; I'm behind a proxy that blocks tinypic, but they make exemptions for attachments through Stack Overflow). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t disable showing policy warnings on Pending Changes. However,
you can **Disable** or **Delete** check-in Policies you don't want.(go to Team -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control... -> Check-in Policy)

Note: To complete this procedure, you must have the **Edit project-level information** permission  .